# PostgreSQL syntax error in param passed in a BeanPropertyRowMapper

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I want to create a dynamic String in my code and add it to a pre-existent query with a BeanPropertyRowMapper. This is the function which creates the string:

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getParams() {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("sideLenght", sideLenght);

    filters = "";

    if(techs.size() > 0) {
        filters += " WHERE (";
        for(String item : techs) {
            filters += "network_type = '" + item + "' OR ";
        }
        filters = filters.substring(0, filters.length()-4);
        filters += ") ";

        if(operators.size() > 0) {
            filters += " AND (";
            for(String item : operators) {
                filters += "mnc = '" + item + "' OR ";
            }
            filters = filters.substring(0, filters.length()-4);
            filters += ") ";
        }
    } else {
        if(operators.size() > 0) {
            filters += " WHERE (";
            for(String item : operators) {
                filters += "mnc = '" + item + "' OR ";
            }
            filters = filters.substring(0, filters.length()-4);
            filters += ") ";
        }
    }
    params.put("filters", filters);

    return params;
}
```

I want to put the string that I create in the function in place of :filters placeholder.
In the query I have 2 :sideLenght placeholders and one :filters, when I execute the code i get this error:

```
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error       at or near "$3"
Posizione: 3939
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:772)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:192)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:199)
at it.ads.etas.bi.dashboard.service.impl.jdbc.CemKpiServiceJDBC.loadGrid(CemKpiServiceJDBC.java:263)
at it.ads.etas.bi.dashboard.view.cem.CEMCoverage.init(CEMCoverage.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
... 60 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$3"
Posizione: 3939
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:560)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:703)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
... 74 more
```

I pass the main SQL query string, params and the `BeanPropertyRowMapper` to the `jdbcTemplate.query` method.
This is the query with placeholders:

```
 SELECT 
    mnc,
    network_type,
    (geom) as geom,
    ROUND(AVG(signal_strength)) AS signalStrength,
    COUNT(DISTINCT (_id)) AS count_network_event
    FROM
    (
     SELECT 
     _id,
     networkstates.mnc,
     data,
        (CASE 
           WHEN network_type = 'EDGE' OR network_type = 'GPRS' OR network_type =      'GSM' THEN '2G'
           WHEN network_type = 'HSPA+' OR network_type = 'HSPA' OR network_type = 'HSDPA' OR network_type = 'UMTS' OR network_type = 'WCDMA' THEN '3G'
           WHEN network_type = 'LTE' THEN '4G'
       ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
            END) as network_type,
     comune,
     ST_GeomFromGeoHash(ST_GeoHash(ST_POINT(longitude,    latitude),:sideLenght),:sideLenght) AS geom,
     signal_strength
     FROM
     (
      SELECT 
      locations.date,
   latitude,
   longitude,
   device.imei,
   device.mnc,
   comuni_italiani.comune
   FROM
   locations
   INNER JOIN device ON device.imei = locations.imei
   AND locations.date BETWEEN device.date AND device.last_date
   INNER JOIN comuni_italiani ON comuni_italiani._id = locations.id_comuni_italiani
  ) AS locations

  LEFT JOIN

  ( 
   SELECT 
   _id,
   device.imei,
   device.mnc,
   network_states.date,
   TO_TIMESTAMP(network_states.network_time/1000) AT TIME ZONE 'cest' AS data,
   network_type,
    signal_strength
    FROM network_states
    INNER JOIN device ON network_states.imei = device.imei
    AND network_states.network_time BETWEEN device.date AND device.last_date
    WHERE signal_strength IS NOT NULL
  ) AS networkstates

  ON networkstates.date BETWEEN locations.date-5000 AND locations.date
  AND networkStates.imei = locations.imei
  AND networkstates.mnc = locations.mnc
  WHERE networkstates._id IS NOT NULL

 ) AS prima
 :filters
 GROUP BY geom, mnc, network_Type--, comune, data
```

The string I want to add is something like this one:
    `WHERE (network_type = 'net1' OR network_type = 'net2' OR network_type = 'net3') AND (mnc = 'mnc1' OR mnc = 'mnc2' OR mnc = 'mnc3' OR mnc = 'mnc4')`
Can someone please explain me where is the error?

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the SQL query with placeholders and an example of what you expect to obtain?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the requested informations.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you use a named parameter instead of a string concatenation.
Try to split your query:

```
query = "..... ) AS prima" + filters;
```

instead of

```
query = "..... ) AS prima :filters";
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I can't do what you say. The string which I want to add to query must be where is my :filters placeholder. I have the query in a separate file and I want put the string in the right place without manipulate the query string directly.

Comment: The problem is: if you use a named parameter it is treated like that, a parameter, it does not simply concatenate your query with the parameter value. Suggestion: edit your file containing the query deleting ":filters" after ".. ) AS prima"

Comment: If I delete the parameter I haven't any way to insert my string inside the query. I can't concatenate with "+" operator in the middle of pre-existent query string.  
How can I do?

Comment: I suppose you use `public <T> List<T> query(String sql, Map<String, ?> paramMap, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)` or something similar, calling it by `jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, yourParamMap, new YourRowMapper())`. If so, you could truncate your sqlQuery and call `jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery + filters, yourParamMap, new YourRowMapper())`